# Error in SqlContext import and parallelize Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

```
line = "Hello, world"
sc.parallelize(list(line)).collect()
```

I obtain the following error

`TypeError: parallelize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'`

I also have an other issue when creating a dataframe from a list of strings with only one column:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
schema = StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True)])
df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(fuzzymatchIntro, schema)
df3.printSchema()
```

I obtain the following error:

```
----> 3 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
AttributeError: type object 'SparkContext' has no attribute '_jsc'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: how did you create `sc`?

Comment: from pyspark.context import SparkContext

from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DFTest").getOrCreate()

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your comment above, **you seem to have initialized `sparkContext` in a wrong way** as you have done

> `from pyspark.context import SparkContext 
>   from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession 
>   sc = SparkContext 
>   spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DFTest").getOrCreate()`

The correct way would be

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DFTest").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

**And `spark` object can do the work of `sqlContext`**

Answer (score 0):

I tried above suggestion in my pyspark in windows using the Jupyter terminal and it has worked. Please find my sample code below which worked for me

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DFTest").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
words = sc.parallelize(["scala","java","hadoop","spark","akka","spark vs 
hadoop","pyspark","pyspark and spark"])
counts = words.count()
print("Number of elements in RDD -> %i" % (counts))
```

Comment: How is this different from Ramesh Maharjan's answer?